# Is there any way to force Volley to refresh an image?

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm currently working on an front end app which relies heavily on Images downloaded from a webservice. To keep it short, the front end downloads from our webservice a given user profile with 3 image slots. If such user uploads a new picture (keeping the same url) it won't refresh until I kill my app so if I were to put it in background and resume the data won't be changed.

Here's a little sample of the code that deals with the ImageNetworkView:

```
mImage = (NetworkImageView) mView
            .findViewById(R.id.profile_network_image);

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) mView
            .findViewById(R.id.profileProgressBar);

    // Cargo image loader
    mLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance(mActivity).getImageLoader();

    if(mLoader!=null && imageUrl!=null){
        mLoader.get(imageUrl, new ImageListener() {


            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                System.out.println("Error loading "+imageUrl+"...");

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                    mImage.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    System.out.println("Done loading "+imageUrl);
                }

            }
        });

mImage.setImageUrl(imageUrl, mLoader);
```

Here are both my VolleySingleton and Cache classes:

```
public class VolleySingleton {
private static VolleySingleton mInstance = null;
private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private ImageLoader.ImageCache mImageCache;

private VolleySingleton(Context context){
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    mImageCache = new BitmapLruImageCache();
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue, mImageCache);
}

public static VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context){
    if(mInstance == null){
        mInstance = new VolleySingleton(context);
    }
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(){
    return this.mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader(){
    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public ImageLoader.ImageCache getImageCache(){
    return mImageCache;
}
```

Cache class:

```
public class BitmapLruImageCache extends LruCache<String, Bitmap> implements ImageCache {

public static int getDefaultLruCacheSize() {
    final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
    final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;

    return cacheSize;
}

public BitmapLruImageCache() {
    this(getDefaultLruCacheSize());

    Log.v("tag", Integer.toString(getDefaultLruCacheSize()));
}

public BitmapLruImageCache(int sizeInKiloBytes) {
    super(sizeInKiloBytes);

}

@Override
protected int sizeOf(String key, Bitmap value) {
    return value.getRowBytes() * value.getHeight() / 1024;
}

@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    return get(url);
}

@Override
public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
    put(url, bitmap);
}
```

Thank you all in advance!

**EDIT:** I've been trying to find a workaround and so far I came up with this:

If I were to place the new image on the cache assigned to the image url when I call getBitmap(url) I'll be getting the new image, but the problem persists, if I close the app with the back button and open it once more volley loads the old image but if I kill the app it will load the new one... Here's the code I've used to place the image on the cache:

```
VolleySingleton.getInstance(mActivity).getImageCache().putBitmap(imageUrl, bmp);

tempBitmap = VolleySingleton.getInstance(mActivity).getImageCache().getBitmap(imageUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

the thing is that image cache is in the memory and the [ImageLoader](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java) will check that before even make a call.

```
        // Try to look up the request in the cache of remote images.
    Bitmap cachedBitmap = mCache.getBitmap(cacheKey);
    if (cachedBitmap != null) {
        // Return the cached bitmap.
        ImageContainer container = new ImageContainer(cachedBitmap, requestUrl, null, null);
        imageListener.onResponse(container, true);
        return container;
    }
```

You will need to clean the cache manually by :

```
VolleySingleton.getInstance(mActivity).getImageCache().remove(imageUrl);
```

or

`VolleySingleton.getInstance(mActivity).getImageCache().evictAll()`